# Multi column foreign key, with hard coded reference value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a ValidationStatus table, with the following (Primary key) columns:

```
Attribute   Code
ADDRESS INVALID
ADDRESS REFUTED
ADDRESS STORE
ADDRESS VERIFIED
EMAIL   INVALID
EMAIL   REFUTED
EMAIL   STORE
EMAIL   UNKNOWN
EMAIL   VALID
EMAIL   VERIFIED
```

Is it possible to establish a foreign key between the address table and this one?

Specifically each address has a validation status; if i could hard code the text, it would be:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Addresses
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Addresses_ValidationStatus
    FOREIGN KEY('ADDRESS', ValidationStatus)
    REFERENCES dbo.ValidationStatus(Attribute, Code)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot do that. the solution is changing the design as below:

1. add a identity or unique integer to dbo.ValidationStatus
2. create foreign key for point to the new integer field

   ```
   ALTER TABLE dbo.Addresses
   ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Addresses_ValidationStatus
   FOREIGN KEY(ValidationStatus)
   REFERENCES dbo.ValidationStatus(NewUniqueField)
   ```
3. add a constraint to Address table to limit to the range of address validation range. for this sample assume your address validation is 1,2,3 and 4. so create a check constraint like

   ```
   ALTER TABLE dbo.Address
   ADD CHECK (ValidationStatus in (1,2,3,4))
   ```

This way you will use the benefit of foreign key.

Another way is having 2 different status table and use a simple FK.

NOTE: In the first method, you have to remember to change the check constraint if you have a new status.

Another method is using combination of character and number like A1, A2, A3, A4 for address status and E1, E2 and so on for email status. for each new entiry you need to pick a character. in this case you can have a simple FK without having multiple tables.